# How to get unsecured page's url in a project?

Tags: symfony-1.4

I want to write a program in my symfony1.4 project which can return/give the unsecured page's url, how can I write this?

I secured the actions with credentials and i used sfDoctrineGuard for security.

If user is not authorized for any pages then that pages show me 401 code from sfwebresponse.

I gave the credentials for every actions.My first question is

1. Now how can i test that the actions are secured.
2. I want to generate a report which contains the every pages url's and respective urls are secured or not?

my routing.yml is like follows:

```
annual_performance_appraisal_details:
  class: sfDoctrineRouteCollection
  options:
    model:                AnnualPerformanceAppraisalDetails
    module:               AnnualPerformanceAppraisalDetails
    prefix_path:          /AnnualPerformanceAppraisalDetails
    column:               id
    with_wildcard_routes: true

annual_performance_appraisal:
  class: sfDoctrineRouteCollection
  options:
    model:                AnnualPerformanceAppraisal
    module:               AnnualPerformanceAppraisal
    prefix_path:          /AnnualPerformanceAppraisal
    column:               id
    with_wildcard_routes: true

apa_question_answer:
  class: sfDoctrineRouteCollection
  options:
    model:                ApaQuestionAnswer
    module:               ApaQuestionAnswer
    prefix_path:          /ApaQuestionAnswer
    column:               id
    with_wildcard_routes: true
```

In my Second(2) question i want a report like follows:

Url: ...../AnnualPerformanceAppraisalDetails
SecurityReport: 401(Athorization requried)

Url: ...../AnnualPerformanceAppraisal
SecurityReport: 401(Athorization requried) or 403 Forbidden

Comment: Please explain more clearly what you wish to accomplish. What have you tried? Do you have any code examples?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**About 1** You can check the status code of the pages. You will need an explicit list of urls to test.

You can probably write something like this :

```
$secured_urls=array('default/index','myModule/index',...);
foreach ($secured_urls as $url) {
    $browser->get($url)
        ->with('response')
        ->begin()
        ->isStatusCode(401)
        ->end();
}
```

**About 2** are you trying to build that report from the tests results?

Comment: yes About 2  i want to build that report from the test result.